# Absolute positioning according to an indirect parent instead of direct parent

Tags: html, css, css-position, absolute

I am just working on a simple example to try to understand the behavior of absolute positioning elements. There is a case that I don't understand.

I have a container, with a card inside of it. I want to add a footer inside of this card, so I put another div inside of it, as follow :

```
<body>
   <section id="experiences">
      <div class="experiences-cards-container">
         <div class="experience-card">
            <div class="card-footer"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </section>
</body>
```

As it is a footer, I want it to be displayed at the bottom of my card. That is the reason why I used absolute positioning to do so :

```
.experience-card .card-footer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

But it seems that the footer element does not get positioned according to its direct parent `experience-card` but to an indirect parent `experiences-card-container`, because I get the following result :

[image]

My question is : Why is the footer element positioned according to an indirect parent and not the card since it is a direct parent ?

Here is the full CSS :

```
html, body 
{
    height: 100%;
}

#experiences {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #ECECEC;
}

.experiences-cards-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    height: calc(100% - 100px);
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}

.experience-card {
    position: "relative";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 280px;
    height: 350px;
    background-color: white;
    margin-right: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 0px #949494;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: left;
}

.experience-card .card-body {
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.experience-card .card-footer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 70px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take out the quotation marks in `position: "relative";` in the .experience-card class and it should work. By making it relative, it will become the context for the absolute positioning in the footer.

Comment: Going from jss to css.. Thanks! I will accept your answer as soon as the 10mins limit is over. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. I added a little explanation about positioning context, but I guess you already know about it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
.experiences-cards-container {
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   max-width: 1200px;
   /* height: calc(100% - 100px); */
   text-align: center;
   margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: Provide some context to the answer, explaining what each rule does.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Hello, world!</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    #experiences {
      height: 100%;
      background-color: #ECECEC;
    }
    
    .experiences-cards-container {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 1200px;
      height: calc(100% - 100px);
      text-align: center;
      margin: auto;
    }
    
    .experience-card {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 280px;
      height: 350px;
      background-color: white;
      margin-right: 20px;
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 0px #949494;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      text-align: left;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .experience-card .card-body {
      padding-left: 10px;
      padding-right: 10px;
    }
    
    .experience-card .card-footer {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0px;
      bottom: 0px;
      height: 70px;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: blue;
      right: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <section id="experiences">
    <div class="experiences-cards-container">
      <div class="experience-card">
        <div class="card-footer"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```